# What if you forget to create a new Git feature branch?

Tags: git

I have three servers, development, staging, and production.  I always have three corresponding Git branches, dev, staging, and master.  Recently I created a new feature branch and pushed it to production.  Then yesterday I began working on another new feature but I forget to delete the old "new feature" branch and start this new work in a newer feature branch.  As a result, my new work is being done in the same branch I used to implement the previous feature.  This seems "unclean" to me.  I want my new work in a new feature branch.  What is the preferred Git process for moving this new work to a new feature branch?

Here's my workflow:

1. I start with my dev, staging, and master branches all being identical.  I then create a new feature branch:

   ```
   git checkout -b new-feature dev
   ```
2. Once I've built the new feature I merge it into my staging branch, push the updated code to my staging server and test it there.
3. If all my tests passes, I new merge the new feature branch into my dev branch.
4. I then merge my dev branch into my master branch and push that master branch to my production server.

At this point, all four branches are identical and I would normally delete the new-feature branch and check out a newer new-feature branch from dev.  But I forgot to do that.

Would the preferred way to move my changed files into a new new-feature branch?

```
    git checkout -b newer-new-feature older-new-feature
    git push origin --delete older-new-feature
    git br --delete older-new-feature
```

Incidentally, I do want to keep the history from the older-new-feature branch in the newer-new-feature branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> At this point, all four branches are identical and I would normally delete the new-feature branch and check out a newer new-feature branch from dev. But I forgot to do that.

Git does not care about the names of your branches, they are merely pointers to commits. Assuming the quoted statement is true, your approach is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to start a new branch from your master branch (or whatever you want to use as the base as your feature) and cherry-pick the revisions that you did "on the wrong branch". Then you can set up the other feature branch to the point where it should be (because it moved with the commits of the new feature, right?). Assuming it's 3 revision that you used for the new feature:

```
git checkout -b new-feature origin/master
git cherry-pick old-feature~3..old-feature
git branch -f old-feature old-feature~3
```

Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

Rebase your changes into the new feature branch:

```
git checkout -b feature-new feature-old
git rebase --onto production <branch-point>
```

Use `gitk` to get the `<branch-point>` (there, were you started to implement the new feature).